# Hibernation error message

Tags: hibernate, asus, nouveau

During Ubuntu hibernation the following messages appear on the screen and they are accumulated until the system is completely restarted. They also can be found in `dmesg` output.

```
[50357.815787] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 0x7241: i2c wr fail: -6
[50357.819721] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 0x7253: i2c rd fail: -6
```

The hibernation itseld is working good (after hacking described in this [article](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug)).

What do these messages mean and should I do anything to avoid them?

My computer is ASUS U40S, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64.

Answer (score 0):

(This message should be a comment.)

This is related with your nVidia graphic card. "nouveau" is its driver. Apparently something is wrong with it. You may refer to your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to get more information.